# Access the data from reference document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the user collection like

```
{
    "_id" : "xyz@xyz.com",
    "name" : "First Last",
    "permission" : ObjectId("5bf4e199e2a30916d6eaeb8c")
}
{
    "_id" : "abc@xyz.com",
    "name" : "Name Last",
    "permission" : ObjectId("5bf4e199e2a30916d6eaeb8c")
}
```

permission is the reference field, part of another collection Permission.
Permission collection is like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bf4e199e2a30916d6eaeb8c"),
    "name" : "Admin"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5548e199e2a30916d6kj7856"),
    "name" : "Super Admin"
}
```

I am fetching the data from user collection using aggregate like

```
    db.user.aggregate([{'$project': {
        '_id' : 1,
        'name' : "$name",
        'permission' : "$permission.name"
        } 
    }])
```

I want to get the content of name from permission collection.
Output is

```
{'name': 'First Last', 'user_company': 'abc', '_id': 'xyz@xyz.com'}
{'name': 'Last Name', 'user_company': 'NEW COMPANY', '_id': 'abc@abc.com'}
```

It should be like

```
{'name': 'First Last', 'user_company': 'abc', '_id': 'xyz@xyz.com', permission : "Admin"}
{'name': 'Last Name', 'user_company': 'NEW COMPANY', '_id': 
'abc@abc.com', 'permission' : "Super Admin"
}
```

How to get the result ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation in mongodb **3.6** and above

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "permissions",
    "let": { "permission": "$permission" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$permission"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "permission"
  }},
  { "$addFields": { 
    "permission": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$permission.name", 0] }
  }}
])
```

Or with the mongodb version prior to **3.6**

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "permissions",
    "localField": "permission",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "permission"
  }},
  { "$addFields": { 
    "permission": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$permission.name", 0] }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to run this kind of query often, it is suggested to store the permission(s) directly on the `user` collection as a string or embedded array (if one user is mapped to multiple users), this way you would not have to do a join.

In general, to do joins you use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). To achieve what you are looking for, you could do:

```
db.user.aggregate([
{ $lookup: { from: "permission", localField: "permission", foreignField: "_id", as: "perm" } },
{ $unwind: "$perm"}, 
{ $project: {  '_id' : 1,  'name' : "$name",  'permission' : "$perm.name" }}
])
```

The `$unwind` stage is needed to flatten the 'permissions'. You can skip that if not needed.